# how to search by integer field as a string (e.g. "priority") with django-haystack?

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I've got a Ticket model that I'm trying to search by its IntegerField priority attribute as a string.  I can get haystack+solr to search by the integer value, but not as a string.

I thought you could do this with a prepare_priority function in the search index class, but I'm not having any luck.  Here's my search_index.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from helpdesk.models import Ticket

class TicketIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    priority = indexes.CharField(model_attr='priority')

    def prepare_priority(self, obj):
        priorities = {1:'critical', 2:'high', 3:'normal', 4:'low'}
        return priorities[obj.priority]

    def get_model(self):
        return Ticket

    def index_queryset(self):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Here's my ticket_text.txt template:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.priority }}
{{ object.body }}
```

Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I figured out how to do this by adding a callable to my Ticket model, but still can't figure out why this can't be done with the `prepare` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why `prepare_priority()` "doesn't work"

A `SearchIndex` is used to convert individual objects of a given model into entries in your Whoosh index. I'll call these entries `SearchResults`, since that's how they show up in the shell. Now, the fields you defined in `TicketIndex` are (of course) present on the `SearchResults` for the `Tickets`:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> q = SearchQuerySet()
>>> ticket0 = q.all()[0]
>>> type(ticket0)
<class 'haystack.models.SearchResult'>
>>> hasattr(ticket0, 'text') and hasattr(ticket0, 'title') and hasattr(ticket0, 'priority')
True
```

That means that `'priority'` shows up twice--once as independent field and once as part of the content of `'text'`. The independent field **does** go through the prepare_X procedure. The text field goes through a template (where `object` refers to the original model object, **not** a dictionary of prepared data).

```
>>> print ticket0.priority
critical
>>> print ticket0.text
OH NOES!!!!
1
There's a problem. Very problematic. Please fix at once.
```

### Fixing it

In the models:

```
PRIORITIES = {1:'critical', 2:'high', 3:'normal', 4:'low'}
class Ticket(models.Model):
  ...
  priority = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITIES.items())
```

Use the automatically provided `get_priority_display` as the `model_attr`:

```
class TicketIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
  ...
  priority = indexes.CharField(model_attr='get_priority_display')
```

Use `get_priority_display` in the template:

```
{{ object.get_priority_display }}
```

Comment: But I thought "prepare" should change the value of the field that is stored in your index?  What is the point of using "prepare" in your SearchIndex, then?

Comment: It does change it... _but only in that field_ (notice above that ``ticket0.priority`` is "critical"). It does _not_ affect the rendering of the template which is used to fill-in the text field (i.e., ``ticket0.text`` has a ``1`` instead). This is because ``{{ object.priority }}`` gets the ``priority`` attribute from the _original Ticket object_, not from the TicketIndex object. If you so desired, you could remove the ``title`` and ``priority`` fields from the TicketIndex and ``text`` would still render just fine.

Comment: You may be wondering what the hell the point of having the ``title`` and ``priority`` fields are if the ``text`` field is the only thing being searched (and can be constructed just fine without having any other fields defined).

The answer is that they are useful when you directly make use of the [SearchQuerySet API](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/searchqueryset_api.html). This allows you to, say, limit the results by date or priority or whatever. Also, a more advanced search form that does this for you makes use of this behind the scenes. So those fields _do_ have some use.